# How to make request call the api throught html

Tags: html, api

i am an api noob i get this following api from rapid api

```
const axios = require('axios');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://aviation-reference-data.p.rapidapi.com/airports/JFK',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API KEY',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'aviation-reference-data.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

try {
    const response = await axios.request(options);
    console.log(response.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

But now i dont know who to integrate this in the following code(i might not using the word integrate correctly)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="card custom-bg w-75 p-4 d-flex">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pb-3 h3 text-left">Group Request Form</div>
            </div>
          <select class="form-select" id="adults"
                            onchange="javascript: dynamicDropDown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                            <option value="umrah" name="umrah">Umrah</option>
                            <option value="hajj" name="hajj">Hajj</option>
                            <option value="Ziarat" name="Ziarat">Ziarat</option>
                            <option value="Others" name="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
            <form id="flight-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md align-items-start flex-column">
                        <label for="origin" class="d-inline-flex">From</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="City or Airport" class="form-control" id="origin" name="origin"
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md align-items-start flex-column">
                        <label for="depart" class="d-inline-flex">To</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="City or Airport" class="form-control" id="depart" name="depart"
                            required>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So i want when i write KHI it show the name of the city and the airport in Box and also in the api the code is case senstive so i dont want that can any body please guide me on this..

Comment: 1. Do not post you api keys. 2. Please change the HTML to be what you want. Right now you have a submit event that is not what you want and an onchange with a function that does not exist and you use IDs like adult an depart and origin that does not match the intention of your code. The URL you call returns a plane type and not an airport like `https://airport-info.p.rapidapi.com/airport/` would

Comment: THanks, sorry for providing wrong api for it

Comment: So where are you going and where are you coming from. Always to or from JFK? The API does not understand Umrah or Hajj. Do you mean MED and JED? And Ziarat - the nearest airport is UET and what is OTHERS?

Comment: This Basically a form to provide our agents to fill forms for the bulk ticketing its not always be JFK (it will from Pakistan cities ) and yes i mean med jed but i want all the airports too , can you please help me with api i want it show the result in input of from or to

Comment: There is not enough information in your question or comments to help you. I am not writing the whole thing for you! Please do some work yourself and then ask when you are stuck. If you are stuck at the very beginning, then perhaps you need to ask external help

Comment: I am not asking you to write a code for me i have the code i  just need the guidance on how to integrate json api in html to show the result in <input> section when somebody write the initial or three letter code of aiport how it open the suggestion box to select like on anyother airline websites have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start - you likely want to "debounce" the input and use a datalist

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

```js
const airportURL = 'https://airport-info.p.rapidapi.com/airport/';
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '6f5a506d55msh85daf68b41d835fp14047fjsn8d1a78348389',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'aviation-reference-data.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const fromCity = document.getElementById('depart');
  const toCity = document.getElementById('arrival');
  const dynamicDropDown = (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const value = tgt.value;
    const url = new URL(airportURL)
    url.pathname += value;
    options.url = url.toString();
    console.log(url.toString())
    try {
      const response = axios.request(options).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
        // fill the datalist 
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };  
  fromCity.addEventListener('change',dynamicDropDown);
  toCity.addEventListener('change',dynamicDropDown);

});
```

Comment: can you guide me regarding this

Comment: I just did. Now do some work yourself and then ask again

Comment: Okay Sir i will then came back to you.